# Algorithm to search for phone numbers in mobile phones?

Tags: algorithm, mobile

What is the general algorithm used by current smart phone operating systems, to search for the names from the contact list?

The contact list is not huge but still, when we type 'A', all names starting with 'A' appear easily. 'A' followed by 'B', will bring names like Abe, Abott etc.,

Comment: Which smart phone OS? Android/iphone/symbian/windows/BB ? You have to be more specific.

Comment: Sharing the algorithm on iOS would be great.

Comment: Why there was a down vote? It is a genuine question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this quickly would be with a trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) - basically, you'd store all the keys in a tree where the root node represents an empty input, and each character you enter takes you down a branch to a subtree which holds all the names starting with the set of letters you've put in so far. There's a good example of using this technique for autocomplete here: http://igoro.com/archive/efficient-auto-complete-with-a-ternary-search-tree/

In your example, entering 'A' would go down the branch labelled 'A' to a subtree holding all names starting with 'A'. From there, entering 'B' would go down the branch labelled 'B' to the next subtree, which would hold all the 'AB' names. Adding new names to a trie follows the same process - follow the right branch for each letter in the name (adding new branches where they don't already exist) until you reach the end of the name, at which point you add it as a leaf.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a common approach / algorithm used?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it's done in current phones (might be slightly different in practice depending on how contacts are stored and the like), but that's usually the standard approach to this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Animatinator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but if I were to guess it would be a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

The idea is that you start at the root of the tree and you trace a path to a leaf node. Every node you go down adds another letter as a suffix.

In your example the tree would look like: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqdhQ.jpg) (not enough rep to embed the image)

Double circles define "accepting" states and are not always a leaf node. As you work down the Trie it will narrow your search:

- Choosing "N" after "A" will reject "ABE" as it is not below it on the path.
- Choosing "E" after "ANN" will reject "ANN" as it is not below it on the path.